# two Field Parameters Connection with two different visuals power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

So I do not know if this is possible in power bi but I have created two parameters and they are not connected to each other. In one parameter I want to group Actual vs Goals measures and the second parameter has the trend of each actual vs goals topic. I created two parameters because I have two main charts one is a line chart for the actual vs goals and one is a bar chart for the trends. what I want to do now in the second bar chart I want to create another bar chart showing the first parameter of actual vs goals. I want when I choose from the first bar chart a parameter I want the second chart to change but not according to the first parameter it will change according to its parameter which is the second which has the actual vs goal for example. when I choose accessories trend I want the second bar chart to automatically select accessories goal vs actual. and when I do choose like hours attend trend I want it to be blank. is it possible? I believe that somehow there has to be a connection but I am not that advanced to think of a way to do it
[image]

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do here - it sounds like it's possible, but can you edit your question to give some specific examples? IE "When you click this box, you'll see this (which you want) and not this (which is what's happening now)." I've seen reports where you can select the metric you want to view as a slicer and it will adjust the charts so it shows that, but I need to see what you're after to be sure.

Comment: i will explain I want those two bar charts to change according to the slicer that appears in the top right. However, the second bar chart which is the one on the left is not connected to the same parameter. and it has different parameter because I want to show specific fields different than the one already existed. I want the new parameter to be disappeared meaning not on the page. so it changes automatically without the user interfering with it. lastly when selecting a specific field from the main parameter I want specific fields to appear in the second chart also blank when otherwise